# Display contents of my website on another website to control data

Tags: php, html

I am needing to show information that is on my website on another website. The content of my website is a simple form that when submitted actually redirects the user to another part of the other website. What is the best way to approach this via `PHP`? I was thinking an `iframe` but not sure if there is another method that would allow for more control or be presented better.

So it would be kind of like this:

```
        <html>
        <head><title>My website</title></head>
        <body>
        <form action="myControllerMethod">
        <input type="name" name="someName">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
        </body>
        </html>
```

Then on the other website it would display basically the same (the form) but when they click submit it goes to my controller method to handle the information and then redirect to a page they want. Which I guess could be hard coded on my end

Comment: maybe you could curl post on that site, then scrape the results, whats that site anyway?

Comment: It's not a specific website. It's a project I am starting and will involve multiple websites and will need to have data displaying from other website onto it. I was thinking about cURL but not to familiar with it.